# Can't always retrieve the path of a process

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the following code:

```
        Using searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " & 1234)
            For Each mgmtObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
                Dim cl As String() = mgmtObj.Item("ExecutablePath").ToString().Split("""")
                Console.WriteLine(cl(cl.Length - 1))
            Next
        End Using
```

NB: 1234 is an example ID which will be the result of GetProcessById.

This works when:

- The process is running under the same user.
- The process isn't a Windows Service (no matter what user it's running as).

In all other cases I've tested I get the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

As an alternative, I also have tried the following code:

```
Private Shared Function GetAssemblyPathAboveVista(ProcessId As Integer) As String
    Dim buffer = New StringBuilder(1024)
    Dim hprocess As IntPtr = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.QueryInformation, False, ProcessId)
    If hprocess <> IntPtr.Zero Then
        Try
            Dim size As Integer = buffer.Capacity
            If QueryFullProcessImageName(hprocess, 0, buffer, size) Then
                Return buffer.ToString()
            End If
        Finally
            CloseHandle(hprocess)
        End Try
    End If
    Throw New Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())
End Function

<DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function QueryFullProcessImageName(hprocess As IntPtr, dwFlags As Integer, lpExeName As StringBuilder, ByRef size As Integer) As Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function OpenProcess(dwDesiredAccess As ProcessAccessFlags, bInheritHandle As Boolean, dwProcessId As Integer) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function CloseHandle(hHandle As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

Enum ProcessAccessFlags As UInteger
    All = &H1F0FFF
    Terminate = &H1
    CreateThread = &H2
    VMOperation = &H8
    VMRead = &H10
    VMWrite = &H20
    DupHandle = &H40
    SetInformation = &H200
    QueryInformation = &H400
    Synchronize = &H100000
End Enum
```

This also only works when:
 - The process is running under the same user.
 - The process isn't a Windows Service (no matter what user it's running as).

In all other cases the OpenProcess function returns 0.

NB: I'm testing on Windows 8.1 with a user that has standard rights (non-administrator). My application *must* run as a standard user.

My question is: what can I do to always be able to retrieve a process path? I only need the path info.

Comment: Seems like a gamble to expect something to always have the same Process ID. Isn't it possible to single out what you are looking for based on a name instead?

Comment: This is purely an example. Of course I first obtain the correct ID.

Comment: Okidoke, though the solution looked to smart for a mistake like that :D

Comment: I think you need to run AS administrator, just try your app as admin to see if you can access others users process info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So indeed even the normal CLR methods cannot read an elevated process' filename, apparently because of a bug in the implementation. They added a new API flag in Windows Vista and up, to be able to read the information, but they have not implemented it in the CLR. The second example you posted seems to have been the same c# source I read, but it needed a little more attention than a C# to VB converter was able to provide.

In any case, here it is, all nicely fitted into an extension method for the Process class.

```
Module ProcessPathExtension
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
    Private Function QueryFullProcessImageName(hprocess As IntPtr, dwFlags As Integer, lpExeName As StringBuilder, ByRef size As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
    Private Function OpenProcess(dwDesiredAccess As ProcessAccessFlags, bInheritHandle As Boolean, dwProcessId As Integer) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Function CloseHandle(hHandle As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    Enum ProcessAccessFlags As UInteger
        All = &H1F0FFF
        Terminate = &H1
        CreateThread = &H2
        VMOperation = &H8
        VMRead = &H10
        VMWrite = &H20
        DupHandle = &H40
        SetInformation = &H200
        QueryInformation = &H400
        QueryLimitedInformation = &H1000
        Synchronize = &H100000
    End Enum

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function Path(ByVal _process As Process) As String
        Dim processPath As String = ""

        ' The new QueryLimitedInformation flag is only available on Windows Vista and up.
        If Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6 Then
            Dim processHandle As IntPtr = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.QueryLimitedInformation, False, _process.Id)
            Try
                If Not processHandle = IntPtr.Zero Then
                    Dim buffer = New StringBuilder(1024)
                    If QueryFullProcessImageName(processHandle, 0, buffer, buffer.Capacity) Then
                        processPath = buffer.ToString()
                    End If
                End If
            Finally
                CloseHandle(processHandle)
            End Try
        Else
            processPath = _process.MainModule.FileName
        End If

        Return processPath
    End Function
End Module
```

Include this module in your project, and you can access the process path through the new .Path method of the Process object:

```
For Each p In Process.GetProcesses().OrderBy(Function(x) x.Id, Nothing)
    Console.WriteLine(p.Id & vbTab & p.ProcessName & vbCrLf & p.Path & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
Next
```

Comment: Your solution has the same problem as described in my question, that is: doesn't work when the assembly is a Windows Service or running under an other user.

Comment: No it does work. Have you tried it? I have and it shows every single process path, including those under System. The original problem comes from the fact that before Vista, there was only one informational structure available to get the information from, and that structure was restricted under the ACL. From Vista on, they added the flag QueryLimitedInformation, which is unrestricted but only contains a limited subset of information about the process, including the path. However they did not modify the Process class to use that new flag. Hence why you must go throught the API.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. This only works when running as a user with administrator rights. I'm testing with standard (non-administrator) rights. When running as a standard user, then the Path returns nothing. Tools like "System Explorer" are able to display the Path info (running as standard user), so in some way it should be possible.

Comment: Well in reality they are not running as standard user, these applications are running as admin when they need to. They start the part of the application that needs admin rights as a new process with administrative privileges. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981778 .

Comment: In general it's not possible. You need at least the same rights as the running process does. As a caller you can set "SeDebugPrivilege" then you can do want you want. So you have to request the rights needed.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any particular reason why you are not using the normal way to do this, so that you can trap exceptions?

```
    For Each p In Process.GetProcessesByName("someprocess.exe")
        Try
            Console.WriteLine(p.MainModule.FileName)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
    Next
```

Or if you really need to get it by ID:

```
    Try
        Dim p = Process.GetProcessById(processId)
        If p IsNot Nothing Then
            Console.WriteLine(p.MainModule.FileName)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
```

Comment: Because several processes with the same name are running.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the nature of your comment, of course you can have multiple processes with the same name. Open Notepad twice and there you go, 2x notepad.exe in task manager. This really is all the code you will ever need for this task, going through WMI or unmanaged code is a waste of time.

Comment: Please read my question. It really doesn't matter how I retrieve the process. The real problem is that I can't read the Filename property.

Answer (score 1):

Alright I tried this out myself. And from what I can see it comes down to rights. You are just not allowed to touch another users processes. Services are normally executed by SYSTEM, which as you probably know is another user acount. Running Visual Studio as administrator will give you what you want.

If you don't want to execute Visual Studio as administrator you would have to set your program to require administrative rights on startup. I expect that this cannot be solved in any other way.

Comment: Tools like System Explorer are somehow able to do this without running with administrator rights.